# Performing mean filtering on an image matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

i'm trying to perform mean filtering on an image in Matlab, i have to make it modular so i have another function for my averaging and then my script calls the function. I run the script and there are no errors but it doesn't seem to do the filtering as the output of the image is no different to the original. Can anyone see where i am going wrong?

```
%input image
image1 = imread('moon.jpg');

%convert to grayscale


%mean filtering
mean = averagefilter2(image1);

image_grey = rgb2gray(mean);

figure;

imshow(image_grey);


%my average filter function%

function img=averagefilter2(image1)
    meanFilter = fspecial('average',[3 3]);
    img = imfilter (image1,meanFilter);
end
```

Thanks!

Comment: my function is saved on its own as averagefilter2.m

Comment: Are you sure it's no different? Have you tried with more aggresive filtering (for example, with 30 instead of 3 in `fspecial`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you show your figures of image1 and image_grey? You can also try to `imagesc(abs(image1-image_grey))` to see the difference between the original image and the averaged one. I ran your code and didn't see problems. I can observed the smooth effect in my sample image.

Remember to apply `rgb2gray` to your image1 as well.

Comment: When would rgb2gray be applied? I applied it after I did the mean? is that correct.

Comment: I mean to your original image since your moon.jpg may also be a rgb image. image1 = imread('moon.jpg');image1 = rgb2gray(image1).